# How do I assign values from an array to x in a for-loop?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, for-loop

I need an explanation as to why my code works in a certain way and not the way I want it to,

```
Dim x As Variant
Dim LetterSht As Variant

 LetterSht = (Array("First Letter", "Second Letter", "Third Letter"))
    
    For x = LBound(LetterSht) To UBound(LetterSht)
```

When I was putting this together I thought I could assign the array values `First Letter`, `Second Letter` and `Third Letter` to `x`, but this simply labels `x` as `0`, `1` and `2`?

The array `LetterSht` does hold the values as `LetterSht(0) = "First letter"` and so on so I expected `x` to also be `First Letter`, I'm clearly not understanding something, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Because the `lbound` starts at 0 and goes to 2 since you have 3 elements.

Comment: `debug.print letterSht(x)` inside the loop will output the value in the array.

Comment: If you want `x` to be the actual value then use a `For Each` loop: `For Each x in LetterSht`  Just an FYI `For` loops are quicker than `For Each` when using arrays: https://analystcave.com/vba-for-loop-vs-for-each-loop/